# Django, Many-to-one relationship with Abstract entities

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Say object contains multiple types of objects (`Models`) in an array, like a `Page`, that could contain a `Post`, `Blog`, `Picture`, in any quantity or order, where the user scrolls down and sees the following element and that depending on the `page`, is next *element* one of these types of *elements*. Thus a `Page` could contain:

1. A `Post`
2. A `Post`
3. A `Picture`

Or something pretty different such as:

1. A `Picture`
2. A `Blog`
3. A `Picture`

An *element* could be an *abstract* entity that has an attribute as a `ForeignKey` relating itself with `Page`, and its inheritance would gain access to that relationship:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    ...
    
class PageElement(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, verbose_name="Page", on_delete=CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Post(PageElement):
    ...

class Blog(PageElement):
    ...

class Picture(PageElement):
    ...
```

With this approach, you can serialize `Page` with a REST serializer, but you wouldn't have access to an `pageElement_set`, instead you would need to call `post_set`, `blog_set`, `picture_set` and loose the order of the objects.

By just adding a `related_name` key in the `ForeignKey`, we get an error:

```
pages.Picture.page: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Picture.page' clashes with reverse query name for 'Post.page'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Picture.page' or 'Post.page'.
```

The question is: **How do you implement such relationships in Django?**

So that you can have an order set of `PageElement` instances, and be able to have the desired order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to query multiple Models in order and you can see that your models are in `Model is a PageElement` relationship, then instead of inheriting from an abstract Model you need to have a `OneToOneField` with a common model:

```
class PageElement(models.Model):
    POST = 'PO'
    BLOG = 'BL'
    PICTURE = 'PI'
    ELEMENT_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (POST, 'Post'),
        (BLOG, 'Blog'),
        (PICTURE, 'Picture'),
    ]
    element_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=ELEMENT_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default=POST,
    )
    # common fields

class Post():
    page_element = models.OneToOneField(
        PageElement,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name = "post"
    )

class Blog():
    page_element = models.OneToOneField(
        PageElement,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name = "blog"
    )

class Picture():
    page_element = models.OneToOneField(
        PageElement,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name = "picture"
    )
```

You can inherit from a common abstract class that has the `OneToOneField` for ease if needed.

Comment: Great!, That does solve the issues, thanks!